# What is the call in the Azure Python SDK to delete a VM from a Scaleset

Tags: python, azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I cannot seem to find the call in the Azure Python SDK for deleting a particular (or set of) VM instance from a ScaleSet.

Comment: Can you provide at least a minimal - reproducible example? What have you done to fix the issue?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`begin_delete_instances`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualmachinescalesetsoperations?view=azure-python#begin-delete-instances-resource-group-name--vm-scale-set-name--vm-instance-i-ds----kwargs-) to delete a particular VM instance in the scale set.